# Multiple requests (pagination) with RestSharp

Tags: c#, concurrency, threadpool, restsharp

I'm new to C# and I need help! I need to send paged data through a client rest. As the data mass is very large, I would like to trigger several requests at the same time, however, only a small part of the data is arriving at the destination. Can you help me with what's wrong?

```
public void SendResultsByFireForget(string env, string transactionId, int days)
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    var proxyDefinition = new WebProxy("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
    proxyDefinition.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    client.Proxy = proxyDefinition;

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(transactionId))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Parameter transactionId is null or empty!");
    }

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(env))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Parameter uri is null or empty!");
    }

    List<Result> listOfResults = Repository.GetResultsByIntervalPerDay(-31);

    if (listOfResults.Count() == 0 || listOfResults == null)
    {
        throw new Exception("The list of results is empty or null");
    }

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (List<Result> page in GetPages(listOfResults, 500))
    {
        var currentPageCopy = page;

        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var currentPage = JSonExtensions.ToJSon(currentPageCopy);
            var request = new RestRequest(
                $"{env.Trim()}/results1/?transaction_id={transactionId.Trim()}",
                Method.POST);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            request.AddJsonBody(currentPage);

            client.ExecuteAsync(request);
        });
        tasks.Add(task);
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: You could try adding an `await` before the `client.ExecuteAsync(request);`, and also adding an `async` here: `Task.Run(async () =>`.

Answer (score 0):

if u can get total result count on first result you can do like this .

```
// RestClient is extented restsharp client you can do your own .

List<User> UserList = new();

// inline method

UserList getUser(int startCount,int limit)
{
  var Data = RestClient.GetData(Url);
  return Data;
}

// another inline for getting total count

int GetOrderCounts()
{
   // get total counts
   var FData = getUser(0,0);
   return FData.TotalRecordCount;
}

  var GetTotalCount = GetOrderCounts();
  for (int ONumber = 0; ONumber <= GetOrderCount; ONumber += 100)
     {
        var Return = GetOrders(OrderNumber, 100);
        if (Return != null)
                UserList.AddRange(Return.Data);
     };
```